# Is this 方言 or a different pitch pattern in 標準語: 出てくる, その他に

Tags: pitch-accent

This is what I hear in [this video:](https://youtu.be/Kd2x7lMlaqM?t=113)

> 日本神話に出てくる神様が一番多いです。その他に自然神だったりとか．．．

I found でてくる{HLLH}, かみさまが{HLLHH}, and そのほかに{HLLHH} kind of strange, because I often hear でてくる{HLLL}, かみさまが{HLLLL}, そのほかに{HLLLL}. So am I hearing it wrong or is this a different pattern?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60249/pitch-accent-in-combination-with-the-%e3%82%92-particle/93159#93159

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the Japanese version of uptalk. So it’s more about intonation than pitch accent.

When pronounced individually, those words are でてくる{HLLL}, かみさまが{HLLLL}, and そのほかに{LHLLL}. When combined, でてくる and かみさまが become でてくるかみさまが{HLLLLLLLL}. However, she raises pitch at the end of each word making it sound almost like でてくるかみさまが{HLLHLLLLH}. She does the same with そのほかに to make it sound like そのほかに{LHLLH}.

However, I noticed that she said チャンネルは{LLLLHL} in the beginning of the video, twice, and this does sound like a dialectal accent.

Answer (score 5):

This is basically a light form of 語尾上げ, which is an intonation phenomenon (used for leading into following phrases when the speaker is casually speaking), not pitch accent.

You are basically hearing it correctly (aside from そのほか{LHLL}), but you should not store such intonation rises as lexical information, compared to the pitch accent which is lexical and should be stored as part of the word in your head.